# Set size of one div while keeping the other dynamic

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website with a sidebar and I am running into some issues with different sized screens. I have figured out that the best way to fix this is to have the sidebar  and the content  each begin as a percentage of the window (30% 70% respectively), but then only allow the content  to re-size, keeping the original 30% of the original window size in the sidebar . How would I proceed with this?

Comment: How do you mean, allow the content to resize?

Comment: Use a css rule to assign a fixed width to the container of the sidebar. Then the rest of the page will automatically adjust.

Comment: So I have two divs, one containing the sidebar (30%) and one containing the content (70%). Let's say I have a 100px wide window. The sidebar would take up 30px and the content 70px. I want to try and find a way so that if the window is re-sized the sidebar div stays at 30px while the content div changes. So If I changed the window size to 70px the sidebar would remain at 30px while the content would change to 40px. If I changed the window size to 150px then the sidebar would stay at 30px and the content would change 120px.

Comment: That makes little sense in my eyes, since you have no control about the initial width of the window. So you have no control about the width of your sidebar, so what the initial 30% are in absolute measurement. What is typically done is to assign a fixed absolute width to a sidebar and either keep that (hard) or allow to manually resize (soft).

Comment: Is it possible to set a fixed absolute width to the sidebar that is a percentage?